# Intercepting source audit records in solaris 11.4 (UNIX)

Tags: c, sockets, unix, plugins, solaris

I am trying to understand how the logs from kernel ring buffer is then captured and modified by plugins like audit_binfile and audit_syslog in solaris OS. I read online that there is a socket through which log messages are sent -> **/dev/log** , so i tried accessing it using the following program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <syslog.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "/dev/log"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    char buf[4096];
    int fd, n, yes = 1;

    // Create socket
    if ((fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Set SO_REUSEADDR option
    if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Bind to /dev/log socket
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, SOCK_PATH, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Read from socket and print log messages
    while ((n = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) > 0) {
        buf[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    // Close socket
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get this error -> **bind: Address already in use** even though I have used SO_REUSEADDR

Please let me know what I am going wrong or is my entire idea on /dev/log wrong? Would really appreciate any insights regarding this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[/dev/log](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37851/log-4d.html) is for syslog, not the audit messages.